# SqPaymentForm is unsecure

Tags: forms, vue.js, security, payment, square

I use Square to implement online payment by credit card. I follow this article: https://developer.squareup.com/blog/taking-payments-online-with-square-and-vue-js/.  Everything is fine, except one thing. Chrome say: **"this form is not secure. autofill has been turned off"**.  This information makes clients feel unsecure.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Use https:// protocol for your form submission

Comment: Chrome says "Automatic Credit Card filling is disabled because this form does not use a secure connection" .

Comment: Use https:// protocol in all links.  What URL are you posting to?  I suggest creating a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on https://codesandbox.io so others can see what you're doing